# Typescript function overloading with type literals

Tags: typescript, google-docs-api

I would like to define an overloaded function with named parameters in typescript. The following code executes but will give me warnings on `init.index` not existing on one of the function signatures.

The reason I want to overload is to provide mutually exclusive properties on the object as defined in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#inserttextrequest) but which are not as such defined in the official [library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/src/apis/docs/v1.ts#L1132).

```ts
export function insertText(init: { text: string, index: number }): docs_v1.Schema$Request;
export function insertText(init: { text: string, segmentId?: string }): docs_v1.Schema$Request {
  return {
    insertText: {
      text: init.text,
      ...(init.index && { location: { index: init.index } }),
      ...(!init.index && { endOfSegmentLocation: { segmentId: init.segmentId } }),
    }
  }
}
```

I've provided a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAOwIYFtgGcxIMbDgEwm3QH0A3ARjgG85RJY4BLBGYKAMxzwGVsALYCiQASAErAAjgFcM8agF8A3HGUAoNQHpNcAApQIZJvmD46IVGAA2wNfWjwO0hNhhMICZgnTsYAFVAYAAoWJhgALho4NhAIuHQYKBYAcwAaLxMQSIRpFAAjdlUASkjCYnIKADo+QWFxKVkEpTtwBzgnFzcPLx9YANiQhDDI2hi4hKSENPjgZLRWAEl8AH5IiZTi0qJSSmqBIVEJGTkaNTg4KGAYaShPajPznt9+uPvHx7HI0JhKsdSH96VIGDMKVFiZOAAMkhUSsRCQXQQIwyoC+Qx+4NAqmK-3e5yBlSCAEJvmCEBDoVFgOSAPIcHizeYwAAy8MRyJ8c2pMCWaNBnKZS2xCiKuMeCgeEolWh0ABEmBwOOwruZLDY4BAOHB+BAAO5wBZwXUQaRWMxWJgAazwMAgcCQYGsAE92s5XO5PIZ2HCkPgUi0GI43Yi4NhLgjgAA5VCmMRIKbAEERB60ZBoNaJFLpBJIWDZXIFKDpan4fP5QoKOAAHyiaeAGcm0xzecQBfY6RsUxg-DLhdUahKBG2FT2tUODRObwuVxudwBofDbGjaHwcYTI3n5zrfJ+dbF7yg8eS9dOeMezZ55NRXn5MFzMH3eJLCyvWRvPxL1ZrpIvcAA1O+lSdsk3abv27wSucUoaNoBomEgVgEHIUDSK4NymKGEAmAGbQdO63QsL0-iBLKyGodclz4EEoyBA2WYom+OTllAmxDuUuw1Ac9THE0OGMHhIaEc8JFkWhlHUdEtHxJmUzZoy3JLKs0mNqxZQ7FUnF1EcjTyA8lwUXO7xCX0UlTu8fxgQSgwUjCtBwtgCIesimIgMKoqWcCJKvlCtl0LS9LyawrIOeyUQCgpZiViKj6Qf2EpAA) with examples of the code and errors I'm seeing.

Additionally I would like to destructure the object parameter as described [here](https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6).

Answer (score 1):

I think you example would work better with a single overload and a union. The only thing you need to do if yo have a union is to discriminate the values somehow.

One option would be to use and `in` typeguard:

```
export function insertText(init: { text: string, index: number } | { text: string, segmentId?: string }): docs_v1.Schema$Request {
  return {
    insertText: {
      text: init.text,
      ...('index' in init && { location: { index: init.index } }),
      ...(!('index' in init) && { endOfSegmentLocation: { segmentId: init.segmentId } }),
    }
  }
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAOwIYFtgGcxIMbDgEwm3QH0A3ARjgG85RJY4BLBGYKAMxzwGVsALYCiQASAErAAjgFcM8agF8A3HGUAoNQHpNcAApQIZJvmD46IVGAA2wNfWjwO0hNhhMICZgnTsYAFVAYAAoWJhgALho4NhAIuHQYKBYAcwAaLxMQSIRpFAAjdlU4AB8omLiEpIQ0+OBktFYASXwAfkjKlNUASkjCYnIKADo+QWFxKVkEmjU4OChgGGkoT2oZ2a8fWADYyNX19fLI0JhB8tS1-cGroIByFkybry8wuAAyV6irIiQ3D12M0BHBBhQb3UBFBRdc77WZXQZBACEtzBIEeLGeMC6bw+tGACHwAHkODw6g0YAAZb6-BD-Hz1PEwZpAkF0snNCFQi6qNYKNQKIA)

Or if you add `index` to both options in the union, but with the extra `index` definition having type `null | undefined` you can also use `== null`:

```
export namespace docs_v1 { export interface Schema$Request {}; };

// Provided example
export function insertText(init: { text: string, index: number } | { text: string, index?: undefined | null; segmentId?: string }): docs_v1.Schema$Request {
  return {
    insertText: {
      text: init.text,
      ...(init.index != null && { location: { index: init.index } }),
      ...(init.index == null && { endOfSegmentLocation: { segmentId: init.segmentId } }),
    }
  }
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAOwIYFtgGcxIMbDgEwm3QH0A3ARjgG85RJY4BLBGYKAMxzwGVsALYCiQASAErAAjgFcM8agF8A3HGUAoNQHpNcAApQIZJvmD46IVGAA2wNfWjwO0hNhhMICZgnTsYAFVAYAAoWJhgALho4NhAIuHQYKBYAcwAaLxMQSIRpFAAjdlU4AB8omLiEpIQ0jNAAfkjnEw4WUxLEaSsrFR9ktFYASXwG+MSU1QBKSMJicgoAOj5BYXEpWQSaNTg4KGAYaShPai3trx9YANjI49PT8sjQmHny1JPb+Y+QhDD5lky4ACEAF4Ol04AAycFRKxEJBuDzXWpZLw-P6gIoKCavW7bD7zL6ohD-IEgnJgyFRYBEgDyHB4wD6VJgABlYfCEIjev0YEMHt8nlymUMMVi3qoTgo1AogA)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The `in` typeguard will work for my case. The second example won't be as interesting as I'm trying to enforce exclusivity. Ideally I'd like an operator that accepts only one single option out of a list (OnlyOneOf<A,B,C..>)